# Difference between shebang flags vs. set builtin flags

Tags: bash, sh, posix

Is there a difference in behaviours with respect to the flags passed to the script on the shebang line vs. using the `set` builtin?

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# do stuff
```

vs.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# do stuff
```

(The question is not specific to `-e` flag but in general for any such flags).

Obviously the `set [flags]` is effective only from the point it's set. But are there any other differences in functionality/behaviour?

Is behaviour same in a POSIX shell, too?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> are there any other differences in functionality/behaviour?

When your file has executable permissions and is executed, then the shebang line is parsed by the kernel.

When your file is executed under the shell like `bash ./script.sh` then the shebang is just a comment. So it will be ignored, and your script will be run with whatever the callers flags are. Putting your flags after the shebang will make sure proper flags are set in your scripts in either case.

The shebang is [parsed by kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/binfmt_script.c#L42). That basically means that the behavior differs from kernel to kernel, from operating system to operating system. Some operating systems didn't handle arguments in shebang at all and ignored all the arguments. Some kernels parse for example `#!/bin/sh -a -b` as `execl("/bin/sh", "-a -b")` some as `execl("/bin/sh", "-a", "-b")`. The parsing of the shebang line to executable and arguments is done by some other code different that your shell. Sometimes if there is a space after `#!` like `#! /bin/sh` utilities don't recognize it as a valid shebang. There's even a recent [linux kernel regression with too long shebang line](https://lwn.net/Articles/779997/).

The behavior of how shebang is interpreted differs between systems, so you can't be certain, so it's best to `set` options after the shebang.

> Is behaviour same in a POSIX shell, too?

A POSIX shell doesn't (have to) interpret your shebang. If you are asking if executing `sh -e` and `set -e` has the same behavior in posix shell, then [yes, the option `-e` on command line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) has the same behavior as `set -e`.

I couldn't find a specification of shebang line nor how should it be interpreted in [posix specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n4217.pdf). I can see in execve documentation:

> Another way that some historical implementations handle shell scripts is by recognizing the first two bytes of the file as the character string "#!" and using the remainder of the first line of the file as the name of the command interpreter to execute.

Those "historical implementations" seem to be very widely used still today.

The shebang line is parsed by the kernel after `exec*` calls. But when you are doing `sh <script>` or `popen` or `system` the *shell* *can* (but doesn't have to) interpret the shebang line by itself as a extension and not rely on kernel implementation, from posix:

> Shell Introduction
>
> 1. The shell reads its input from a file (see sh), from the `−c` option or from the `system()` and `popen()` functions  defined  in  the  System  Interfaces  volume  of  POSIX.1-200x.  If  the  first line   of   a   file   of   shell   commands   starts   with   the   characters"#!",the   results   are unspecified.

As for bash, it looks like bash [first tries execve](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/master/execute_cmd.c#L5457), then if it can't find the reason why kernel failed to run the executable, [if the file has a shebang](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/master/execute_cmd.c#L5540), then [it parses shebang on its own](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/master/execute_cmd.c#L5331) to find out the interpreter.

Comment: Between yours & Chepner's answer/comments, we can conclude that it's better to use `set` (in case this makes any difference if at all).

Comment: `the shebang line is parsed by the kernel` I found this bash source code : https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/master/execute_cmd.c#L5493 which seems to process shebang as well.

Comment: The shell has to know how to run other scripts, so that when you type `./script` it has to know how to run `script`. Optionally the shell can know how to interpret shebang as an extension, which comes (or would come) in handy on systems that doesn't interpret shebang on it's own. So, shebang is interpreted by the kernel in `exec` calls, but when you type `./script` in your shell the shell can interpret the shebang on it's own. Which is only adding to confusion.

Comment: Let's take your example. If `./script` contains `!#/bin/python`, bash will pass `./script` to `exec`, or it will pass `[/bin/python ./script]` to `exec` ?

Comment: `bash will pass ./script to exec` First. But don't trust me, test it yourself. In `strace bash -c './script'` you can see `execve("./script", ["./script"],`. Then _if_ `exec` call fails, then bash will try to parse shebang.

Answer (score 5):

Some operating systems may disallow or limit the use of arguments in the shebang. No such limit would apply to a `set` command in the script itself.

Comment: Other than that, there's absolutely no difference ( subshells, sourced scripts, and so on)? Is this specified somewhere in POSIX standard or bash manual (I couldn't find anything on bash(1))?

Comment: That's the problem: shebangs aren't standardized at all. It's a widespread feature that such a comment, in some way or other, can be used to specify an interpreter for a script, but no agreement on how it does, or should, work in practice.

Comment: As far as `bash` is concerned, setting an option from the command line is the same as setting it using `set`. (Of course, a command-line option takes effect immediately upon shell startup, while the `set` command takes effect, well, whenever `set` ends up being executed.)

Answer (score 1):

The manpage states that "-e" has different behaviour depending on POSIX mode or not.
Other than that, I have never noticed a difference between setting parameters and extending shebang.
Why are you asking this question?

Comment: As noted the question is not specific to `-e`. Also that it behaves differently in posix mode isn't relevant (as long as the behaviour remains the same in both ways of specifying the flag).

Comment: "Why are you asking this question?" - because I am curious and I couldn't find the answer myself from the Internet/bash man page ;-)

Comment: I am sorry, my question was phrased a bit wrong - I was curious as to what problem you might have run into in order to ask that question in the first place.

Comment: No worries :) It wasn't specific to any issues I have/had. I have seen both ways of specifying the flags in our codebase. So was curious to know if there are differences and whether either is preferred.