# How is it determined which shell runs a script?

Tags: sh, zsh, shebang

There are several shells in my Linux, like bash, sh, zsh...

And I know there are at least 3 ways to specify a shell to execute my shell scripts:

1. Specify in shebang, like`#!/usr/bash`
2. Specify in the command line when executing, like`sh MyScripts.sh`
3. Specify in `$SHELL` (say, `SHELL=zsh`), and execute the script like `./MyScripts.sh`

So, my big question is when there is conflict between these three ways, which rule has the highest priority? Which the lowest one?

And what if I do `sh MyScripts.zsh`? You see, the suffix and binary don't match.

Comment: According to my experiments, it seems that Rule#2 is the highest, and Rule#3 is the lowest. Is that right?

Comment: If the script is executable, whether or not `SHELL` is used depends on the how you start the script. For example, `bash` will execute a script with no shebang itself, rather than using the value of `SHELL`.

Comment: @BenjaminW: (3) does not work **in general**, although there are some programs which obey the SHELL variable. I wouldn't rely on it. (1) and (2) are safe. (2) is useful in that you don't need executable rights on the script in question, (1) is useful in that the user of the script does not have to think what language the script is written in.

Comment: @user1934428 I just edited the question, not ask it, did you mean to tag me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File names are just file names. They can be anything, except zero byte and `/`. Suffix is just for *humans*. They can be anything. They do not matter on Linux.

When you type `cmd ./filename` then *shell* executes command `cmd` with argument `./filename`. It does not matter if `cmd` is `python`, `zsh`, `bash` or `wc`, it is getting executed with the first argument set to `./filename`. Now what the program does with *the string* `./filename` is up to the program. `sh` is a program, that when it has one argument that does not start with a leading `-`, then that program `sh` reads that a file named as the first argument and interprets its content. So `sh ./filename` executes `./filename` as a `sh` script.

"Interpreter" is a type of programs, that are meant to interpret the content of a file in a specific programming language. For example program `python` is a Python programming language interpreter. `sh` meant to be an interpreter for POSIX-compatible Shell programming language. Etc.

When you type `./filename` *in shell*, then *shell* ([or kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61978350/difference-between-shebang-flags-vs-set-builtin-flags/61978606#61978606)) checks if the file has executable permissions set. If it does, it reads two first bytes of the file. If the two first bytes of the file are `#!`, then it reads to the end of the first line of the file. Then the first line is interpreted as the command to run the filename with. So when you do `./filename` and you have `#!anything_here` then the shell runs `anything_here ./filename`.

`SHELL` is unrelated here, it's sometimes not even set. It's usually a variable that is set to the path to the current interpreter. So if you want to run a file with the same interpreter as currently running, you would type `$SHELL ./filename`, so shell can expand variable `SHELL` and run the program the same as current interpreter you are running on.

Comment: In the 3rd paragraph, what if I execute `sh ./MyScript.sh` while this MyScript.sh begin with`#!/bin/zsh`? Which interpreter is called finally? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `sh ./anything` will execute `sh`.  And comments start with `#`, `#!/bin/zsh` is a comment for shell interpreter.

Comment: There is a difference between executing program `sh` with `./anything` as first argument, and executing program `sh` with `./anything` passed as input.

Comment: And what if I execute`./MyScript.sh` while this MyScript.sh is executable and there is no shebang in it? Which interpreter will be called?

Comment: Then it is an ELF file (binary file), and when it is not, you will get an error. Seems trivial to try it out.

Comment: Seems like [bash helps people](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/execute_cmd.c#L5873), and if the first 80 bytes of the file are in ASCII, then it interprets it by spawning with bash. Otherwise you'll get `cannot execute binary file` error.

Comment: So when I do `./anything` (this 'anything' file contains some shell code and there is no shebang), bash (or say the os default shell) is called?

Comment: @WilliamAllwaysWin, No, a shell would have no reason to launch `bash` when it's told to execute `./anything`. KamilCuk listed one exception: `bash` will launch `bash` as if you had used `bash ./anything` if the file in question is a text file that doesn't start with `#!`.

Comment: Just to clarify: when you run `./anything` and it has no shebang and the first 80 bytes of the file are in ASCII it will run `sh ./anything`. In most cases `sh` is link to another shell