# How does Linux decide which shell to use for a script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I had trouble with a shell script that ran correctly when started manually from bash, but didn't run correctly when started by crontab.

It turned out I made a typo and started the script with "#/bin/bash" instead of "#!/bin/bash". When I ran it manually from bash ("./script.sh"), bash was invoked to interpret it. But when the script ran from crontab, /bin/sh was invoked instead!

Why the difference? A script with an executable bit set should be as good as a binary executable file, so why is it interpreted with different shells (/bin/bash vs. /bin/sh) depending on whether it is executed from bash or from crontab? I understand the script didn't specify the shell path due to my typo, but shouldn't a script run with the same shell regardless of which process invokes it?

Comment: Maybe a related question with an answer for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69643212/how-is-it-determined-which-shell-runs-a-script

Comment: Yes, it answers it, thanks! The SHELL variable is set to /bin/bash when I run the script interactively from bash, but it is apparently not set when cron runs my script. Thus the different interpreters.

Comment: If there is no #! line, the shell itself decides what it is using. The convention is to use `sh` to run it, and I think that most languages adhere to this convention. _bash_, AFIK, uses `bash` to run such a script. Some may have a look at the environment variable named `SHELL`, but I don't believe that this mechanism is really burned into Linux itself. As for `cron` you can specify using the `SHELL=` setting in the crontab, which shell to use, if there is no #! in your script. However, explciitly specifiying the shell seems more reasonable to me.

Comment: What _exactly_ did you put in crontab? What is your SHELL= cron setting? Which bash version and sh version do you have installed?

Comment: I just put "* * * * * /home/user/my-script.sh" into crontab. I never did a SHELL= setting for crontab. I have whatever versions of sh and bash came with ubuntu 19.04.

I did a test script that recorded the SHELL variable, and SHELL was indeed set to /bin/sh when running from crontab. So this explains everything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is it determined which shell runs a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69643212/how-is-it-determined-which-shell-runs-a-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should be as good as a binary executable file, so why is it interpreted with different shells (/bin/bash vs. /bin/sh) depending on whether it is executed from bash or from crontab?

Because it was programmed that way. Or it was standardized that way. Because it should do that. Because of historical reasons. Because it was always like that.

> How does Linux decide which shell to use for a script?

Is specific to the specific shell you are using. Below is about Bash shell. Any other may act differently.

Bash shell [first tries execve](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/master/execute_cmd.c#L5457). Kernel then tries to parse the shebang.

If execve fails, then Bash if it can't find the reason why kernel failed to run the executable, [checks the file shebang on its own](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/master/execute_cmd.c#L5540), then [Bash parses the shebang on its own](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/master/execute_cmd.c#L5331) to find out the interpreter and runs it. (I copied this part from [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61978606/9072753), which is also relevant).

If the file however does *not* have a shebang, then Bash then checks if it's a binary file with [`check_binary_file` function](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/bash/blob/master/general.c#L568), which is rather really simple. And then, if `check_binary_file` is also false, then the file content *is executed as a bash script*.

(Common error I do, is I forget shebang in python scripts, and `import` is an ImageMagick X11 command that traps the cursor).

This behavior is standard and in line with specification and all shells act that way, with the change that they run themselves. The [POSIX sh spec in Command Search and Execution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) states:

> 2. If the command name contains at least one , the shell shall execute the utility in a separate utility environment with actions equivalent to calling the execl() function defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017 with the path and arg0 arguments set to the command name, and the remaining execl() arguments set to the command arguments (if any) and the null terminator.
>
>    If the execl() function fails due to an error equivalent to the [ENOEXEC] error, the shell shall execute a command equivalent to having a shell invoked with the command name as its first operand, with any remaining arguments passed to the new shell. If the executable file is not a text file, the shell may bypass this command execution. In this case, it shall write an error message and shall return an exit status of 126.

Answer (score 2):

The Hashbang

```
#!/path/to/interpreter
```

specifies which interpreter should be use to interpret the text file. If it is missing (and the typo caused it to be missing) the system has no clue and chooses a default instead, usually /bin/sh

Naturally, the system could try to find out which language has been used in the file. But that doesn't solve the problem. In fact, some people enjoy writing text files that can be interpreted by different interpreters. The system would be screwed again if it finds such a script.

The far more sane approach is to let the developer decide which interpreter to use. Hence the hashbang

Comment: I understand that. But when I invoked the script from bash in the same way I would invoke a binary executable ("./script.sh") the system for some reason chose bash to interpret the script, and not /bin/sh. Why?

Comment: @cuckoo : Because the designers of bash have chosen this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The cause for different behavior turned out to be that the SHELL environment variable was set to /bin/bash when I used bash interactively, thus resulting in bash processing my script. But SHELL was set to /bin/sh when my script was executed as a cron job, hence the difference.

Comment: Always beware when using cron. It runs with an extremely reduced environment. Good that you were able to answer your question yourself. This way you'll never forget it :-)

Comment: keep in mind that `/bin/sh` doesn't necessarily mean the bourne shell; in many (linux) distributions `/bin/sh` may be a symlink to, or an outright copy of, another shell, eg, in my Ubuntu 22.04 env: `file /bin/sh` ==> `/bin/sh: symbolic link to dash`

Comment: This isn't correct; bash *always* runs shebangless scripts in itself, no matter what `SHELL` is set to. cron, on the other hand, uses `SHELL` to determine what shell to use to run the command in the crontab file (i.e. the command that says to run your script), but that's not necessarily what'll be used to run the script. For example, if you set `SHELL=/bin/zsh` in your crontab, zsh would be used to run a command like `/path/to/script`, but when zsh is told to run a shebangless script it runs it under /bin/sh instead of itself.